# Numerically approximate the ground state wave function of the finite potential well problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-principle

I am trying to numerically approximate the ground state wave function of an embedded square well, but when I plot the wave function, I get an unreasonable result.

### Problem Setup

Here is the set up of the problem:

[image]

I am assuming that the only region of non-zero potential is between $-a$ and $a$. Hence, the potential can be given by

$$
V(x)=
\begin{cases}
V_0,-a<x<+a\\
0,|a|<x<|b|\\
\infty,x=|b|
\end{cases}
$$

### My Approach

My approach to solving this problem numerically is to approximate the wave function as a linear combination of basis functions, where the basis functions are given by

$$
|\phi_i(x)\rangle=A_i\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)
$$

I am only considering the even solutions. $A_i$ is the normalization constant, and for this problem I determined it to be

$$
A_i=\sqrt{\frac{1}{b}}
$$
The wave function is then approximated by the linear combination

$$
|\psi(x)\rangle=\sum_{i=0}^N C_i|\phi_i(x)\rangle
$$

for a fixed number of basis elements $N$. The $C_i$'s are the expansion coefficients and can be determined by diagonalizing the Hamiltonian to find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors. For example, for the ground state the lowest eigenvalue should be the ground state energy and its corresponding eigenvector should be the coefficient vector. The elements of the coefficient vector are the $C_i$'s in the wave function's expansion.

So, the task is to determine the Hamiltonian matrix elements and diagonalize it for a fixed number of basis elements. I am deriving the Hamiltonian matrix elements by solving

$$
H_{ij}=\langle\phi_i|\hat{H}|\phi_j\rangle
$$

The Hamiltonian for this problem is given by

$$
\hat{H}\equiv-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)
$$

Hence, the matrix elements are computed by

$$
H_{ij}=\langle\phi_i|\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)\right)|\phi_i\rangle
$$

Based on the geometry of the problem and the potential, this can be solved by setting up the following integral expression:

$$
H_{ij}=\frac{2}{b}\left[\int_0^{+a}\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V_0\right)\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx+\int_{+a}^{+b}\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx\right]
$$

This integral can be simplified by breaking it into "potential" and "kinetic" parts.

$$
H_{ij}=\frac{2}{b}\left[V_0\int_0^{+a}\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int_0^{+b}\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx\right]
$$

Where the kinetic part can integrated from 0 to $+b$. Doing the 2nd derivative of the cosine term in the potential part, the expression becomes

$$
H_{ij}=\frac{2}{b}\left[V_0\int_0^{+a}\cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\pi(2j+1)}{2b}\right)^2\int_0^{+b}
cos\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx\right]
$$

For the off-diagonal elements, the this is solved as

$$
\boxed{H_{ij}=\frac{V_0}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a\pi(2i+1)}{b}\right)}{i-j}+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a\pi(i+j+1)}{b}\right)}{i+j+1}\right)}
$$

For the diagonal elements, $i=j$ the the integral expression becomes

$$
H_{ii}=\frac{2}{b}\left[V_0\int_0^{+a}\cos^2\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\pi(2i+1)}{2b}\right)^2\int_0^{+b}\cos^2\left(\frac{2i+1}{2}\pi\frac{x}{b}\right)dx\right]
$$

This integral is solved as

$$
\boxed{H_{ii}=V_0\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{\sin\left(\frac{a\pi(2i+1)}{b}\right)}{\pi(2i+1)}\right)-\frac{(2i+1)^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{8b^2m}}
$$

### Results

In my calculations, I assume that $V_0=-6eV$, $a=3\overset{\circ}{A}$, $b=20\overset{\circ}{A}$. To simplify calculations, I set $\hbar=1$ and $m=1$, which means that lengths need to be converted into units of Bohrs and energies need to be converted to units of Hartrees. I do those conversions in mt code.

The exact ground state wave function is supposed to look like a Gaussian centered about the origin. However, when I diagonalize the Hamiltonian for a certain number of basis elements, I get something very strange. Let's consider the case of $N=5$ basis elements:

[image]

I would expect that as I increase the number of basis elements, that it should keep roughly the same shape and converge to the exact solution. However, the shape completely changes as I increase $N$. Here is $N=100$:

[image]

### Code

Here is my Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def angstrom_to_bohr(l):
    
    '''
    Function to convert lengths from units of angstroms to bohrs
    '''
    
    converted_length = l / 0.52917725
    
    return converted_length

def ev_to_hartree(V):
    
    '''
    Function to convert energies from units of eV's to hartrees 
    '''
    
    converted_energy = V / 27.211396
    
    return converted_energy

def build_hamiltonian(N, V_0, a, b):
    
    '''
    Function to build Hamiltonian matrix for a given number of basis element, V_0, a, and b
    '''
    
    a = angstrom_to_bohr(a)
    b = angstrom_to_bohr(b)
    V_0 = ev_to_hartree(V_0)
    
    hamiltonian = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range(N):
        
        for j in range(N):
            
            if i == j:
                
                epsilon_i = -((2 * i + 1)**2 * np.pi**2) / (8 * b**2)
                V_ii = V_0 * (a / b + np.sin((a * np.pi * (2 * i + 1)) / b) / (np.pi * (2 * i + 1)))
                matrix_element = V_ii + epsilon_i
                
            else:
                
                matrix_element = (V_0 / np.pi) * (np.sin((a * np.pi * (i - j)) / (i - j)) + np.sin((a * np.pi * (i + j + 1)) / b) / (i + j + 1))
                
            hamiltonian[i, j] = matrix_element
            
    return hamiltonian

def main():
    
    '''
    Main function
    '''
    
    a = 3
    b = 20
    V_0 = -6
    
    N = 5
    hamiltonian = build_hamiltonian(N, V_0, a, b)
    
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(hamiltonian)
    
    lowest_eigenvalue_idx = np.argmin(eigenvalues)
    gs_energy = eigenvalues[lowest_eigenvalue_idx]
    C_vector = eigenvectors[:, lowest_eigenvalue_idx]
        
    b = angstrom_to_bohr(b)
    x = np.linspace(-b, b, 100)
    psi = np.zeros(len(x))
    for i in range(N):
        
        psi = psi + C_vector[i] * np.sqrt(1 / b) * np.cos(((2 * i + 1)) * np.pi * (x / (2 * b)))
    
    plt.plot(x, psi)

if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I don't is an issue with my derivation of the matrix elements, my code, or perhaps something else. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused by your units.  I don't think you can consistently set the value of the potential in eV, the values of the length scale in angstroms, *and* at the same set $\hbar$ and $m$ to 1. (Or rather, I think that this means you are actually setting a particular mass $m$.  Can you clarify that point?  This makes it difficult to write my own code that is consistent with yours.  Typically, it's a good idea to choose scaling variables (such as $V_0$ and $b$) for energies and lengths, and use those to non-dimensionalize the equation *before* coding it up.

Comment: @march With $\hbar=m=1$, I believe that angstroms become Bohrs and eV's become Hartrees. Is that right? I convert to those units when doing my calculations.

Comment: @march I think that you are right that the odd solutions cannot be neglected. That may be at least one of the issues, in addition to the ground state.

Comment: @march why do you think the OP does not start at $i=0$? He doesn’t say so for the formula and the code shows that it starts at $i=0$ (using range).

Comment: You don’t need the odd states, the ground state is non degenerate so is of definite parity. Either you use only odd states, or you use only even states (since the ground state is probably even, best use the latter)

Comment: Please note that debugging code is [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: @march looking at the code, for the mass unit, I think the OP meant $m=m_e$ (electron mass) in SI so that it is consistent with his energy conversion to Hartree. I agree that it is not clear just by looking at the text.

Comment: Step potentials are exactly solvable (except for a diagonalization of a finite matrix which may require finding the roots of a higher order polynomial), are they not?

Comment: It seems like your approach is running into numerical stability issues. I am actually confused as to which regime you are working for. I mean, is $V_0$ deep enough to have a state? Or are you only considering states with $E>0$? I would, instead, try to solve analytically $E<0$ and $E>0$, and in part of the solution there will be a need to numerically match conditions. Solutions obtained this way is easier to trust, and then you can have something to compare to. Smart choices would make the equations trivial.

Comment: Disagree with people saying that the non-inclusion of odd states is the problem. This system is symmetric under inversion of the $x$ coordinate. Therefore all energy eigenstates can be an eigenstate of the parity operator - and will have 0 overlap with any wavefunctions with the opposite parity eigenvalue. This is all a fancy way of saying that the groundstate will have no overlap with parity -1 eigenfunctions. The groundstate doesn't have a zero so it has to be parity +1 (parity -1 wavefunctions all have a zero at x=0)

Comment: @AXensen.  I should have deleted my first comment--I will do that now--but my second comment was me realizing that they were only looking for the even solutions.

Comment: @LPZ.  In the post, the OP explicitly writes down the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^N$, but later I realized that since OP is using `range(N)` in the Python code, they are explicitly starting at 0.  It was a mismatch between the math in the post and the code that confused me.  I meant to delete me earlier comment but forgot.

Comment: Oh ok, I missed the index in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

You have two competing effects: kinetic energy an potential energy. When the potential energy is stronger, you do expect to have a ground state that is roughly gaussian in the pothole. However when the kinetic energy only the ground state of the free electron will dominate.

As march recommends, it is best to first make everything dimensionless. Before, you specify $a,b,V_0$ in SI, you need to also specify $m$ in SI for consistence. I think that you implicitly meant $m=m_e$. Now you can change to dimensionless quantities by setting $r_B=m_e=\hbar=1$ (Bohr’s radius and electron mass). I get $a=\frac{3}{0.529}=5.7$ $b=\frac{20}{0.529}=39$ and $|V_0|=\frac{6}{27.211}=.22$.

This shows how big the potential is, since in dimensionless units:
$$
V_0\gg b^{-2}
$$
so you’d expect the potential to dominate and your intuition of a localized state in the pothole is correct.

I suspect that there is an issue with the code an that you don’t take into account the ground state. Indeed, your final result seems to be a superposition of the desired ground state and the state $|\phi_0\rangle$. This is weird because by skimming the script it seems that you do take it into account. Anyway, I’ll let you find your mistake on your own since debugging is off-topic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What does the statement "roughly gaussian in the pothole" come from? If the pothole has capacity for many states, then the groundstate can be approximated by $\cos(\pi x/2a)$ (cosine, not gaussian). If the pothole is far too small to fit states, then the groundstate will be $\cos(\pi x/2b)$, with a perturbation in the pothole

Comment: In the limit of $b\gg a$ and  the tails outside the pothole is exponential. Granted the argument in the exponential is linear in $x$ and not quadratic, so it is rather closer to a Laplace distribution. Thanks to the smooth interpolation in the pothole, you’d therefore expect it to vaguely ressemble a gaussian (hence the  “roughly”, I wasn’t attempting to be rigorous).